# How do units of measurement of factor inputs affect production function fit?

Tags: measurement

I'm trying to fit a CES production function by running grid search over nonlinear parameters of capital share and elasticity. When I change units of measurement or normalise data, I get different estimates. How is that possible if elasticity of substitution is measure-free and should, in principle, be the same for whatever units of measurement?